# Windows Precise Timing : Error in CreateTimerQueueTimer or system_clock::now()?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, visual-studio-2012, c++-chrono

I am working towards achieving +/- ms timing precision. I want the time between threads to be 10ms, but when I measure the time I get something closer to 15ms.

I am trying to understand if the problem is due to the way I am measuring time or if I am measuring the time accurately and there is some delay introduced by  `CreateTimerQueueTimer`

My code looks like

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int current;
long long* toFill;
void talk()
    {
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> tp = \
        chrono::system_clock::now();
    toFill[current++]=chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count() ;
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    HANDLE hTimer;
    current = 0;
    toFill = new long long[1000];
    CreateTimerQueueTimer(&hTimer,NULL, 
        (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)talk,NULL,
        0,10,0);
    _sleep(3000);
    DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL,hTimer,NULL);
    for (int i = 1;i<current;i++)
        {
        cout << i << " : " << toFill[i]-toFill[i-1]<< endl;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Output looks like

```
...
161 : 16 <-- Should be 10
162 : 15
163 : 16
164 : 16
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accuracy of timers and the real time clock in Windows is limited by the clock tick interrupt rate.  Which by default tocks 64 times per second, 1/64 sec = 15.625 msec.  Just like you saw.

Increasing that rate is actually possible, call [timeBeginPeriod(10)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624%28VS.85%29.aspx) at the start of your program to get 10 msec accuracy.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the real time clock in Windows".  Schedulable timers indeed are only as accurate as the clock interrupt, but the time can be queried with much much better precision.

Comment: The suggestion is a good one, but I don't think the statement about clock accuracy is true. The question I want to understand is if `sleep()` is wrong or if the `clock::now()` is wrong. When I increase the granularity by setting `timeBeginPeroid(10)` my sleep appears to wakeup faster (a similar code with mutex has them unlock quicker). This would hint that the `clock::now()` is always reporting the right time and that `sleep()` is the cause for the discrepancy. Sleeps too long. Perhaps, implementing a spinlock would clear this up.

Comment: I don't know what _sleep() is.  Use Sleep() instead.  Regardless, it should have nothing to do with the interval between talk() callbacks.

Comment: @HansPassant, this is also not a bad suggestion, but I still need to know if discrepancies come from my measuring instrument (`now()`) or from the amount of work I am claiming to do `sleep()`. The way I understand your post, `sleep(10)` will sleep exactly for 10, but my metering (with `now()`) maybe inaccurate. I don't think this is the case.

Comment: I just don't know what you are talking about.  I explained where the 16 msec intervals come from and how you can change it.  If you have some new problem or have "discrepancies" then I can't guess what that looks like, I can't see your screen from here.  If you are hoping for *exact* 10 msec intervals then scratch that, Windows is not a real-time operating system.  Good luck with it.

Comment: @Mikhail - the error is in the call to Sleep.  Sleep uses the OS timer interrupt (whose interval specified in timeBeginPeriod) to determine when to wake back up.  If you set the timer interrupt at a 10ms interval and call Sleep(1) you will actually sleep for 10ms (at least!)

Answer (score 1):

CreateTimerQueue is not meant for precise timing. It uses thread-pools underneath, which may introduce significant delays.

From MSDN's [CreateTimerQueueTimer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) document:

> Callback functions are queued to the thread pool. These threads are subject to scheduling delays, so the timing can vary depending on what else is happening in the application or the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you need better resolution than 15 ms then this will hopefully help:

[Implement a Continuously Updating, High-Resolution Time Provider for Windows](http://web.archive.org/web/20130308151045/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx)

(Thanks [@MaxTruxa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438798/windows-precise-timing-error-in-createtimerqueuetimer-or-system-clocknow/14439136?noredirect=1#comment63093062_14439136) for the update on the link)

<strike>As for measuring time: If I had access to Windows or Visual Studio I would give [high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) a shot. (I switched to Linux 7 years ago, sorry, I can't check it myself.)</strike> As Xeo wrote: "high_resolution_clock is a typedef for system_clock with MSVC."

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` is a `typedef` for `system_clock` with MSVC. :/

Comment: @Xeo Thanks, I didn't know that. Edited the answer accordingly!

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, but the article is available through [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130308151045/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx).

Comment: @MaxTruxa Thanks, updated the answer, and acknowledged your help!